# Fatal: Could not open database: resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, synchronization, ubuntu, database

I get this error when I run the `geth upgradedb` command:

```
I0317 08:29:57.792433    4202 chaincmd.go:137] Upgrading blockchain database
I0317 08:29:57.792491    4202 database.go:71] Alloted 16MB cache to /home/'my_user_name'/.ethereum/chaindata
Fatal: Could not open database: resource temporarily unavailable
```

Though the first time I run the `geth --console` command, my machine synced with the Ethereum Blockchain.

What Im I missing?

Comment: Why do you want to run `upgradedb` in first place? This error looks like another `geth` instance is already running.

Comment: I was trying to see if I had the blockchain on my machine. Thanks though it was because another instance of geth was running.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your `geth` client is already running in the background. You can attach to it by typing:

```
$ geth attach
```

in your command line. This will allow you to run commands on the `geth` client console.

Comment: For any of those wondering why this may be the case - if you have your ETH wallet application open (Mist, Ethereum Wallet, etc.), then that is your node on the network, so if you have Ethereum and geth installed on your computer, that terminal (or command line) window is simply connecting to this existing node

Answer (score 0):

In my case, since the Ethereum Wallet is running already so close the Ethereum Wallet then call `geth console` again it will work.